# How to input image file from user and then base64 encode it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, base64

I trying to take image as a file input from the user and the display it as a base64 encoded string.
Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript – Convert Image to Base64 String</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="file" name="upload" id="file" accept="image/*">
    <br>
    <br>    
    <button type="button" onclick="showResult()">Show Source</button>
    <div id="image-source">Image Source :</div>
    <br>
    <div>Data URL:</div>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toDataURL(src, callback) {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhttp.onload = function() {
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onloadend = function() {
                    callback(fileReader.result);
                }
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(xhttp.response);
            };

            xhttp.responseType = 'blob';
            xhttp.open('GET', src, true);
            xhttp.send();
        }



        showResult(){
            var x = document.getElementById("file").value;
            document.getElementById("image-source").innerHTML = x;
            toDataURL(x, function(dataURL) {
            // do something with dataURL
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = dataURL;
        });
        }


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Do I need to store the source of the image seperately to encode it ? Is there a simpler way to encode a user uploaded image ??

Comment: Why do you want to mess with base64!?  A waste of CPU, 33% extra storage, and headaches for usually no benefit.

Comment: Hi @Brad actually I am trying to send the image to vision api, the api accepts either base-encoded files or gcloud bucket file links or image url (public), I want the results dynamically so I thought base encoding would be best. If know any better method I'd be more than glad to use it .

Comment: Wow, what sort of API won't accept binary image data?  That'd be far better.

Comment: According to the documentation https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/request#providing_the_image , these are only listed ways. I am new to programming, any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: Do you want to convert an image a user has selected (using the file input element) to a base64 dataURL on the client side? I'm not understanding why the code is using  XMLHttpRequest  and what its purpose is.

Comment: @traktor53 I went through this article https://bytenota.com/javascript-convert-image-to-base64-string/ and it used FileReaderApproach ( i was just trying ways to encode the image ) . And yes I want to convert an image a user has selected (using the file input element) to a base64 dataURL on the client side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple example converting the first image selected using the file browse button. File reading occurs on the client side after an image has been selected. File reading is *asynchronous* so I've promisified the file reading function:

```js
"use strict";

const fileDataURL = file => new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    let fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = () => resolve( fr.result);
    fr.onerror = reject;
    fr.readAsDataURL( file)
});

function showResult(file) {
    fileDataURL( file)
    .then( data => (document.getElementById("result").textContent = data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

```css
#result {
   width: 80%;
   font-family: monospace;
   overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<p>
<input type="file" onchange="showResult( this.files[0]);" accept="image/*">
<div>Data URL:</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```